# WPF/MVVM: switching between views

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to learn WPF/MVVM, and I'm currently working on how to switch between views. I've started by finding some example to study in the interntet. The one I'm using is quite simple: two views (named "Home and "Account") that only display a label, to keep the xaml and VM simple, and a main window with two buttons to switch between the views.

The DataTemplates are declared in the App.xaml file (together with the namespaces), so they should be global to the whole project:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:HomeViewModel}">
        <views:HomeView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:AccountViewModel}">
        <views:AccountView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

The way I've understood it, the trick is done by a third VM (called MainViewModel.cs) that implements a SelectedViewModel attribute that keeps track of the VM that must be displayed, plus and ICommand bound to the buttons:

```
        private BaseViewModel _selectedViewModel;
        public BaseViewModel SelectedViewModel
        {
            get { return _selectedViewModel; }
            set
            {
                _selectedViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedViewModel));
            }
        }
        public ICommand UpdateViewCommand { get; set; }
```

MainWindow.xaml looks like this:

```
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Margin="10" Width="200" Content="Home" Command="{Binding UpdateViewCommand}" CommandParameter="Home"/>
            <Button Margin="10" Width="200" Content="Account" Command="{Binding UpdateViewCommand}" CommandParameter="Account"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

In a separate class file (UpdateViewModel.cs) the UpdateViewModel class implements the Execute method as follows:

```
        public void Execute (object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter.ToString() == "Home")
            {
                viewModel.SelectedViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
            }
            else if (parameter.ToString() == "Account")
            {
                viewModel.SelectedViewModel = new AccountViewModel();
            }
        }
```

I hope I've given the idea without boring you. It all works and lets me understand the basics. Now I wanted to try a variant, i.e. take one view (the "Account" one) and implement a button that would switch directly to the other view. I thought all I had to do was to bind the button to the UpdateViewModel class, and initially I modified the Account.xaml code as follows:

```
        <Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding Path=UpdateViewCommand}" CommandParameter="Home"/>
```

The program runs, but when I click on the button in the Account view, nothing happens. So I changed this to something more complex:

```
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <src:MainViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
...
    <Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding Path=UpdateViewCommand}" CommandParameter="Home"/>
```

But the result is the same. I suspect it has to do with the binding, but can't see how to change it. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO!

Your button bindings are done relative to the current DataContext, so binding to UpdateViewCommand in your AccountView (say) will try to bind to the UpdateViewCommand in your AccountViewModel, rather than your MainViewModel.

There are two ways to solve this. The first is to change your button bindings to bind to the parent's view model instead:

```
<Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.UpdateViewCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" CommandParameter="Home"/>
```

A major disadvantage here, of course, is that the visual hierarchy your child views reside in may not always be as predictable as this.

The second (better) way is to add UpdateViewCommand handlers to each of your child view models, and then have them pass control on to whatever you actually want to handle it. In practice you would typically create a base class for all your children, to reduce code duplication, and you would create a service (e.g. INavigationService) for them to call. Your MainViewModel (say) would then implement this interface, and you would use dependency injection to inject that reference into the child view models at their moment of creation (or just have the parent pass itself directly into their constructors, if you don't want to use a full DI framework).

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the excellent suggestion. The first method you proposed actually helped me better understand that particular form of binding, that I had considered but was not completely clear about. The second method looks very interesting but it's perhaps a bit too advanced for my current knowledge, especially when you mention dependency injection. Can you suggest some good article on this?

Comment: @GiovanniNieddu DI is one of those things you may already be using to an extent, without realizing it. It's a way of implementing Inversion of Control, but takes care of all the messy details of passing references around your project. It greatly simplifies your architecture design, once you start using it you'll never look back. There are many DI frameworks for C#, but Ninject is the best IMO, and Christiaan Verwijs
wrote up [a really good tutorial](https://medium.com/the-liberators/a-step-by-step-guide-to-using-ninject-for-dependency-injection-in-c-68a125bd7fa4) on both it and DI as a whole.